# How to restart a loop with eval with timeout in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

```
while (!exists("j")) {
    i <- 1

    repeat {
        tryCatch(expr = {
            print(i)

            raw.result <- evalWithTimeout(Sys.sleep(i), timeout = 3)

            if (i == 1) {
                j <- i
            } else {
                j <- c(j, i)
            }

            i <- i + 1
        }, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
            rm("j")
        })
    }
}
```

The above code is getting stuck at `i=4` and keeps executing the function for `i=4`, however I want it to restart from `i=1`, whenever there is an error.

Can someone please guide on where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code`TimeoutException` is unable to find `j` as it is evaluated in a different environment. Even if it was able to find it, nothing would change. As `tryCatch` is stopping an error from breaking a `repeat` loop, thus `repeat` will continue with the current `i`. You could explicitly break out from the `repeat`, but in that case you have deleted `j`, thus your `while` will stop.

I am not quite sure why you need `while` loop here.

Here is a modification of your code that will work as you want. 
Fist explicitly set `i <- 1`, and rest it again to `i <<-1` (Note `<<-` as `i` is one environment above tryCatch).

```
i <- 1

repeat {
  tryCatch(
    expr = {
      print(i)

      raw.result <- R.utils:evalWithTimeout(Sys.sleep(i), timeout = 3)

      if (i == 1) {
        j <- i
      } else {
        j <- c(j, i)
      }

      i <- i + 1
    },
    TimeoutException = function(ex) {
      i <<- 1
    }
  )
}
```